# Proving theorem in Coq, the number of occurances in a list is <= the lenght of this list

Tags: coq

```
Fixpoint num_occ (x : nat)(xs : list nat) : nat :=
  match xs with
  | [] => 0
  | (y :: ys) => if eq_dec x y
               then 1 + num_occ x ys
               else num_occ x ys
  end.


 
Theorem exercise2
  : forall x xs, num_occ x xs <= length xs.
Proof.
```

I tried, but i have no idea of how can i prove that, i am iniciating in this language....

i tried this:

intros x xs.
induction xs.
simpl.
reflexivity.
case 1.
simpl.
destruct x.
simpl.

and show this:

2 goals
x, n : nat
______________________________________(1/2)
0 = n
______________________________________(2/2)
num_occ x (n0 :: l) = n

Answer (score 0):

I think case 1 is not necessary. Try this:

```
Theorem exercise2
  : forall x xs, num_occ x xs <= length xs.
Proof.
  intros x xs. induction xs; simpl.
  - reflexivity.
  - destruct (eq_dec x a).
    + apply le_n_S. assumption.
    + apply le_le_succ_r. assumption.
Qed.
```